# Can I get a scholarship from graduate school in physics if my GPA below 3?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I'm fresh physics graduated student from *University of Jordan* -Middle East-, My GPA is below 3, so Can I get a scholarship from graduate school in physics at -**US**- if my GPA below 3, If *yes* what is the Admission Requirements for it ?!

Comment: As an international student with a GPA below 3, I'm afraid it's going to be difficult to get _admission_, let alone financial support.

Comment: See [this article](http://3dpancakes.typepad.com/ernie/2005/03/re_phd_with_low.html) that JeffE wrote a while ago. Although times are a little different now, I wouldn't say *no*. There are [plenty](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8380/) of other [questions](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/324/) on this topic already. Grades aren't everything.

Comment: @Moriarty: The fact that this is an _international_ admissions case complicates things immensely, and reduces the likelihood of success.

Comment: As @Moriarty says, things have changed even in the ten years since I wrote that article.  I do know of more recent examples of successful academics with low GPAs, but they all had significant undergrad research experience.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the school, depends on which classes dragged your GPA down and how those intersect with what you want to study in grad school, depends on what you have done in your field since your undergraduate study... I don't think there is a single answer that will be correct for all students and all schools.

Comment: Something else to keep in mind is any previous practical experience with whatever program the student is going into.  I've seen sub-3.0 GPA students land a PhD track position because they had about 3 years worth of applicable experience working in a lab as an undergraduate.  But as @keshlam said, this situation depends on a lot of factors.