# Am I not fit for grad school if I have a bad GRE score? Should I give up?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states

I have taken the GRE four times and got 148 Verbal, 157 Quantitative, and 3 on Writing.

By the way, English is not my first language. I am a foreigner that works in his home country. I want to do a PhD in the USA, but I can not get a descent GRE score.

Does these results say I am not fit to do a PhD?

I can not get good reference letters. I graduated from a developing country university which has no graduate programs and Faculty works part time. I did electrical engineering.

Comment: My department doesn't require GRE scores, so I literally don't know what the numbers mean; therefore, your scores definitely do **not** suggest to me that you are unfit for a PhD.  On the other hand, a lack of good recommendation letters may be a significant barrier to admission, regardless of your fitness.

Comment: Have you asked about recommendation letters? Part time faculty may have contacts and networks through industry jobs.

Answer (score 1):

As some answers for a similar question have pointed out regarding GRE scores, the answer could be [*maybe*](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8380/importance-of-gpa-and-gre-scores-for-grad-school-admissions?rq=1). Language too, is not necessarily a hard barrier to doing a PhD in the US, as long as the potential advisor can overlook it.

*However,* I would strongly urge you to find good reference letters as having both poor letters *and* poor scores is generally a pretty big red flag, or at the least significantly reduces the competitiveness of your application.

You may still have a chance by contacting faculty directly in less popular or lower ranked schools, which may have a shortage of applicants. This does vary on the field.

Comment: @gomenasi: Where can I find low ranked Electrical Engineering Schools?