# Pure mathematics graduate scholarships in Europe for international students with a bachelor degree only in engineering?

Tags: funding, mathematics, europe, changing-fields, international-students

**Short Question**: Are there any graduate (PHD or masters) pure math scholarships available in Europe for  international (non-European) engineering students ? I would like to get examples.

**Long Question:** I am a mechanical engineering major who wants to study mathematics at a graduate level. Due to extreme circumstances, I wasn't able to get a bachelor degree in mathematics. However, I self studied lots of mathematics. I self studied graduate math topics as well. Some mathematicians at my university were following some of my mathematical progress for 2-3 years. I expect to get excellent recommendation letters from them. I also coauthored a paper with one of these mathematicians (not published yet). I also participated in a national math competition held at my country four times and achieved first position. Thus, I believe the only thing I am lacking is a bachelor in mathematics. Another problem is that my GPA in engineering isn't too high (because I lacked interest in my engineering courses), it lies in the open interval ]3.3,3.35[.

Specifically, I would like to know about scholarship opportunities in Europe where a person with a strong math background but without an undergraduate degree in mathematics is likely to be accepted.

---

An example of a scholarship that I know of is this one :

https://diploma.ictp.it/application-admission/diploma-programme

However, it doesn't meet the criteria for this question since it requires applicants to have a bachelor degree in mathematics.

Comment: This question differs very little from http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8040/acceptance-into-graduate-math-programs

Comment: Amr, refer to this answer, might fit your case as well http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24474/phd-in-europe-without-scholarship-from-non-european-homeland/26626#26626

Answer (score 4):

In the nordic countries the funding is provided by the PI, and the hard criteria are very relaxed. From a random PhD offer in one Swedish university:

> **Entry requirements**
>
> To meet the general entry requirements for
> third-cycle studies, an applicant must have
>
> 1. taken a second-cycle qualification
> 2. completed course requirements for at least 240 higher education credits, including at least 60 second-cycle higher education credits,
>    or
> 3. otherwise acquired essentially the same knowledge in or outside Sweden.

(As Dave Clark points out, second cycle qualification is a masters degree.)

Other universities I have checked require the equivalent of four years of course work, with a project of at least 15 credits ECTS or equivalent. And I remember some just require three years (but good luck proving you are ready for a PhD with that!).

This is only the hard requirements imposed by the university. Then, you just need to show your future supervisor that you have the necessary knowledge, and convince him you are the best candidate.

The best thing? Application is free, you just need to spend a few hours composing good letters.

Comment: Second cycle qualification is a masters degree.

Comment: I was mainly translating what second cycle means, as I don't think it is a common term.

Comment: For additional clarification purposes, are EU education credits equivalent to US credits?

Comment: `one credit generally corresponds to 25-30 hours of work`; source: http://ec.europa.eu/education/tools/ects_en.htm dunno how its in US tho'